# Is there a nice idiom for adding a new list or appending to a list (if present) in a dictionary?

Tags: dictionary, python, idioms

This is the second time I've implemented something like this and I suspect there has to be a better *(read: more pythonic)* way to do this:

```
phone_book = {}

def add_number(name,number):
  if name in phone_book:
    phone_book['name'].append(number)
  else:
    phone_book['name'] = [number]
```

I realize the code can likely be made more concise with conditional assignments, but I suspect there's likely a better way to go about this.  I'm not interested in only making the code shorter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `dict`'s [`setdefault`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) like this:

```
phone_book.setdefault('name', []).append(number)
```

Answer (score 8):

Yep, you can use [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects). With this `dict` subclass, when you access an element in the dictionary, if a value doesn't already exist, it automatically creates one using a constructor function you specify.

```
from collections import defaultdict
phone_book = defaultdict(list)

def add_number(name, number):
    phone_book[name].append(number)
```